# Cannot get Rexster to work with Orient-DB - Some sort of permission/user-login error?

Tags: orientdb, tinkerpop, rexster

I have installed Orient-DB 2.0.2 and have got it running. I can access it via http://localhost:2480/ and access the demo 'GratefulDeadConcerts' database with user 'admin' and password 'admin'.

I have installed Rexster Server 2.6.0. Using the default config, I am able to access some demo databases via http://localhost:8182/ and 'the dog house'.

I copied 'orientdb-client-2.0.2.jar' and 'orientdb-enterprise-2.0.2.jar' into Rexsters 'ext' folder, as per instructions I found. Whilst fault-testing the below, I copied every jar file from the Orient-DB 'lib' folder into Rexsters 'ext' folder (another stackoverflow question had this as the answer).

I have then edited the rexster.xml file (after stopping the server), and inserted the following (I also disabled the demos)...

```
<graph>
    <graph-name>orientdbsample</graph-name>
    <graph-enabled>true</graph-enabled>
    <graph-type>com.tinkerpop.rexster.OrientGraphConfiguration</graph-type>
    <graph-location>plocal:E:/DATABASES/orientdb-community-2.0.2/databases/GratefulDeadConcerts</graph-location>
    <properties>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>admin</password>
    </properties>
    <extensions>
        <allows>
            <allow>tp:gremlin</allow>
        </allows>
    </extensions>
</graph>
```

Upon restarting the Rexster server, the following is output...

```
[INFO] Application - .:Welcome to Rexster:.
[INFO] RexsterProperties - Using [E:\DATABASES\rexster-server-2.6.0\config\rexst
er.xml] as configuration source.
[INFO] Application - Rexster is watching [E:\DATABASES\rexster-server-2.6.0\conf
ig\rexster.xml] for change.
[WARN] GraphConfigurationContainer - Could not load graph orientdbsample. Please
 check the XML configuration.
[WARN] GraphConfigurationContainer - GraphConfiguration could not be found or ot
herwise instantiated: [com.tinkerpop.rexster.OrientGraphConfiguration]. Ensure t
hat it is in Rexster's path.
com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationException: GraphConfiguration cou
ld not be found or otherwise instantiated: [com.tinkerpop.rexster.OrientGraphCon
figuration]. Ensure that it is in Rexster's path.
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.getGraphFrom
Configuration(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:142)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.<init>(Graph
ConfigurationContainer.java:54)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.reconfigure(XmlRex
sterApplication.java:99)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.<init>(XmlRexsterA
pplication.java:47)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.<init>(Application.java:97)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.main(Application.java:189)
Caused by: com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationException: Check graph
 configuration. Missing or empty configuration element: graph-location
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.OrientGraphConfiguration.configureGraphInstance
(OrientGraphConfiguration.java:64)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.getGraphFrom
Configuration(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:124)
        ... 5 more
[WARN] GraphConfigurationContainer - Check graph configuration. Missing or empty
 configuration element: graph-location
com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationException: Check graph configurat
ion. Missing or empty configuration element: graph-location
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.OrientGraphConfiguration.configureGraphInstance
(OrientGraphConfiguration.java:64)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.getGraphFrom
Configuration(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:124)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.<init>(Graph
ConfigurationContainer.java:54)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.reconfigure(XmlRex
sterApplication.java:99)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.<init>(XmlRexsterA
pplication.java:47)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.<init>(Application.java:97)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.main(Application.java:189)
[INFO] GraphConfigurationContainer - Graph tinkergraph -  not enabled and not lo
aded.
[INFO] GraphConfigurationContainer - Graph tinkergraph-readonly -  not enabled a
nd not loaded.
[INFO] GraphConfigurationContainer - Graph gratefulgraph -  not enabled and not
loaded.
[INFO] HttpReporterConfig - Configured HTTP Metric Reporter.
[INFO] ConsoleReporterConfig - Configured Console Metric Reporter.
[INFO] HttpRexsterServer - HTTP/REST thread pool configuration: kernal[4 / 4] wo
rker[8 / 8]
[INFO] HttpRexsterServer - Using org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.LeaderFollower
NIOStrategy IOStrategy for HTTP/REST.
[INFO] HttpRexsterServer - Rexster Server running on: [http://localhost:8182]
[INFO] RexProRexsterServer - Using org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.LeaderFollow
erNIOStrategy IOStrategy for RexPro.
[INFO] RexProRexsterServer - RexPro thread pool configuration: kernal[4 / 4] wor
ker[8 / 8]
[INFO] RexProRexsterServer - Rexster configured with no security.
[INFO] RexProRexsterServer - RexPro Server bound to [0.0.0.0:8184]
[INFO] ShutdownManager$ShutdownSocketListener - Bound shutdown socket to /127.0.
0.1:8183. Starting listener thread for shutdown requests.
```

I have tried various settings for the graph, but nothing works (and all documentation indicates my config is correct).

As a test, I change the graph-location to end with 'testdb' (instead of 'GratefulDeadConcerts'). Upon starting the server, Rexster outputs the following, and a database is created alongside the existing 'GratefulDeadConcerts' database.

```
[INFO] Application - .:Welcome to Rexster:.
[INFO] RexsterProperties - Using [E:\DATABASES\rexster-server-2.6.0\config\rexst
er.xml] as configuration source.
[INFO] Application - Rexster is watching [E:\DATABASES\rexster-server-2.6.0\conf
ig\rexster.xml] for change.
[INFO] RexsterApplicationGraph - Graph [orientdbsample] - configured with allowa
ble namespace [tp:gremlin]
[INFO] GraphConfigurationContainer - Graph orientdbsample - orientgraph[plocal:E
:/DATABASES/orientdb-community-2.0.2/databases/testdb] loaded
[INFO] GraphConfigurationContainer - Graph tinkergraph -  not enabled and not lo
aded.
[INFO] GraphConfigurationContainer - Graph tinkergraph-readonly -  not enabled a
nd not loaded.
[INFO] GraphConfigurationContainer - Graph gratefulgraph -  not enabled and not
loaded.
[INFO] HttpReporterConfig - Configured HTTP Metric Reporter.
[INFO] ConsoleReporterConfig - Configured Console Metric Reporter.
[INFO] HttpRexsterServer - HTTP/REST thread pool configuration: kernal[4 / 4] wo
rker[8 / 8]
[INFO] HttpRexsterServer - Using org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.LeaderFollower
NIOStrategy IOStrategy for HTTP/REST.
[INFO] HttpRexsterServer - Rexster Server running on: [http://localhost:8182]
[INFO] RexProRexsterServer - Using org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.LeaderFollow
erNIOStrategy IOStrategy for RexPro.
[INFO] RexProRexsterServer - RexPro thread pool configuration: kernal[4 / 4] wor
ker[8 / 8]
[INFO] RexProRexsterServer - Rexster configured with no security.
[INFO] RexProRexsterServer - RexPro Server bound to [0.0.0.0:8184]
[INFO] ShutdownManager$ShutdownSocketListener - Bound shutdown socket to /127.0.
0.1:8183. Starting listener thread for shutdown requests.
```

Everything looks good based upon the above. I stopped and started the server, and it was the same. I then closed Rexster and connected to the testdb database using the Orient-DB webapp. I logged in using user admin:admin, and everything looked good. I then restarted Rexster server, but got the first 'error' I posted above (the same error as the 'GratefulDeadConcerts' database produces).

I don't know what is wrong. Does anyone know?

Just thought I would mention that I am using Windows 7 x64, and installed Java jdk1.8.0_31.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and after some searching found a subtle documentation flaw. In [orientdb wiki](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/Rexster.html) we see the next rexter.xml example:

```
...
<graph-type>orientgraph</graph-type>
<graph-file>url-to-your-db</graph-file>
...
```

Inside [Rexter documentation](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Specific-Graph-Configurations#orientdb) the next:

```
...
<graph-type>com.tinkerpop.rexster.OrientGraphConfiguration</graph-type>
<graph-location>local:C:/data/graph/graph</graph-location>
...
```

As you can see, the second tag (graph-location) differences in these docs,  original Rexster docs(graph-location) is right one. And I suppose that you use tag from orient docs, inspite of that in rexter.xml part you stated *here* is right, because you get a warning in your start log:

```
[WARN] GraphConfigurationContainer - Check graph configuration. Missing or empty
 configuration element: graph-location
com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationException: Check graph configurat
ion. Missing or empty configuration element: graph-location
```

Take a note on that **graph-location** and check your config file carefully.